# PDF Anchor tag to another page

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, anchor

Is there a way to go to other pages in a PDF document wiht out having to provide the full URL int the Link tag?

Everywhere I look, before the HTML is converted to PDF, they use link tags wiht an HREF that contains the site and pdf location.
If they download this file, why would I want them to link to the website to view another page?

Trying to get the table of contents to link(without the full URL) to the sections of the PDF? Is this even possible or is BookMarks the only way?

There is no use for the full URL, because the PDF's are reports and diferent for everyone and not saved in a specific location thats open to everyone. But the reports are long and I'm having trouble getting bookmarks to work in Adobe Reader 9 and/or winnovative pdfconverter.

Comment: Something of note: bare `#page=NNN` anchors work in Google Chrome. If a company really needs this feature, you can always tell them the generated PDFs need to be open with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are creating this document, but most likely the link action is being set to an URL destination instead of a "Go To View" destination.

Consider though that while it would seem to be a reasonable optimization to say, "oh, hey, this link is going to the same URL from which the document came, so I should just change it to a "Go To View" destination!", there is no guarantee that any two loads of the same URL will result in the same HTML twice.